# Chrome DevTools - Set WebGL version

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, google-chrome-devtools, webgl, webgl2

In [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/), is it possible to set the version of WebGL and/or disable WebGL for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to find an answer to my question yet, I have found something that addresses the reason I asked it.

In Three.js, if you want to test your code with WebGL 1, you can replace your `WebGLRenderer` with `WebGL1Renderer`:

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
    // ...
});
```